# To show thumbnail images to import

Tags: php

in the db table contains information that links to the image.

```
<P> <IMG Src=\"http://bismute.dothome.co.kr/test1.jpg\"> </P>
<P> <IMG Src=\"http://bismute.dothome.co.kr/test2.jpg\"> </P>
```

From the board to show thumbnails of each image is.

However, creating a thumbnail showing the existing function as follows:

Is to show only one image.

```
// Function to create thumbnails
public function ThumbNailImg($Contents) {
    $ThumbImg = stripslashes($Contents);
    preg_match_all ("/<img[^>]*src=[\"']?([^>\"']+)[\"']?[^>]*>/i", $ThumbImg, $ThumbImg);    
    return $ThumbImg[1];
}

// Get part of the image
$ThumbImg = $BBS->ThumbNailImg($res2 [CONTENTS]);

if (count($ThumbImg) > 0) {    
    $ThumbImg = "<img src='".$ThumbImg[0]."' width='200px'>";
    $ThumbImg2 = "<img src='".$ThumbImg[1]."' width='200px'>";
    $ThumbArea = "<td width='200px' style='position:relative'> <a class = 'bbsList' style = 'position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; clip: rect (0px 190px 110px 0px);'> ". $ThumbImg." </ div> </ a> </ td><td valign='top'> ";
    $ThumbArea2 = "<td width='200px' style='position:relative'> <a class = 'bbsList' style = 'position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; clip: rect (0px 190px 110px 0px);'> ". $ThumbImg2." </ div> </ a> </ td><td valign='top'> ";
}
```

Although it is possible to get a thumbnail of test1.jpg, test2.jpg to create a thumbnail of what it is you need to change is wondering.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The default layout that shows a list of posts on the bulletin board in the
<IMG SRC=""> tries to display the images.

Contents tagged in one only, regardless of the number of images and thumbnails to the output, in line with this, the number of tagged image thumbnails are trying to print.

Comment: I cleaned up your code a bit, it had multiple syntax errors. Please take a moment to format your code, your questions will probably get an answer more quickly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$ThumbImg = $BBS->ThumbNailImg ($res2 [CONTENTS]);

if (count ($ThumbImg)> 0) {

$ThumbImg = "<img src='".$ThumbImg[0]."' width='200px'>";
$ThumbImg2 = "<img src='".$ThumbImg[1]."' width='200px'>";
```

to this:

```
$ThumbImgArray = $BBS->ThumbNailImg ($res2 [CONTENTS]);

if (count ($ThumbImgArray) > 0) {

$ThumbImg = "<img src='".$ThumbImgArray[0]."' width='200px'>";
$ThumbImg2 = "<img src='".$ThumbImgArray[1]."' width='200px'>";
```

Notice I changed the first variable name `$ThumbImg` to `$ThumbImgArray` to prevent overwriting this variable in the latter statement.